# Vuejs 2 + splice

Tags: vuejs2

I'd like to know why when I use splice in VueJS 2 it removes the last index instead of the index that I want.
Have a look at this example https://jsfiddle.net/tiagomatosweb/t121ufk5/

```
removeSection: function(index) {

            this.sections.splice(index, 1)
    },
```

What I am missing?

**UPDATE**

I found the reason why it wasn't removing the right array. Actually, it was, but the select wasn't updating.

1) I was using the internal model var for the select v-model="fruitId", for instance.
2) It has to be external var, that comes from the section, as you wrote v-model="section.fruit".

That makes the trick.

Then I come back to use the Vuejs index and worked very well.

https://jsfiddle.net/tiagomatosweb/t121ufk5/2

Comment: can you write this in the answer and accept your own answer. It is helpful for other user to know this question has some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why it wasn't removing the right array. Actually, it was, but the select wasn't updating.

1) I was using the internal model var for the select v-model="fruitId", for instance.
2) It has to be external var, that comes from the section, as you wrote v-model="section.fruit".

That makes the trick.

Then I come back to use the Vuejs index and worked very well.